# Надежная реализация автоматического подключения клиентов к серверу

Tags: сеть, администрирование, клиент-сервер, vpn, связь

Есть около сотни локальных метеостанций. Основа - Raspberry Pi или иные одноплатники с UNIX. Связь с внешним миром они производят через 3G-модемы. IP адреса серые.
Стоит задача управлять этими станциями(калибровка, установка алармов, удаленное обновление ПО станции, получение данных по запросу).
Можно было бы реализовать сервис в сети, куда все станции по-умолчанию бы "стучались" и получали бы информацию или отправляли данные POSTом. Но в случае переезда сервера(из-за внезапных блокировок, привет, РКН) такая технология провалится, т.к. придется ездить по всем блокам и вручную изменять сервер, в который они стучатся. А также, я думаю, страдает оперативность управления.
Есть идея использовать VPN, организуя P2P-сеть и управлять станциями напрямую по TCP, кидаясь в нужный адрес пакетами. Но как сообщить всем устройствам новый VPN, если сервер сменится? Можно с помощью стороннего сервиса, в который будут стучаться устройства перед подключением к VPN для получение актуального адреса сервера. Но если этот сервис "кончится", то опять все сводится к объезду устройств и ручной работе.
Может кто имел подобный опыт или я прошел мимо какой-то технологии, которая полностью решает проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Все что вам нужно - это отдельный домен для сервера. Напомню, что в отличии от IP-адресов домены не подвержены ковровым блокировкам.

Просто прописывайте на метеостанциях доменное имя вместо IP-адреса. Если IP-адрес изменится - вы просто измените DNS-запись и через какое-то время все метеостанции узнают новый адрес сервера. Временем переключения можно управлять через параметр TTL в настройках зоны DNS.

Comment: "Какое-то время" может быть недопустимо. В таком случае поможет свой DNS, где изменения можно применять быстро. Но он тоже подвержен внезапной блокировке.

Comment: @Konstantin свой DNS не нужен, достаточно своей зоны. Кстати, адрес сервера DNS тоже можно изменить в любой момент..

Comment: Домены нет. Но DNS-сервер может быть точно также заблокирован как любой IP(ковровая блокировка которых только процветает). Свой нужен, т.к. время прменения изменений на стороннем - неизвестно. Задача - максимально отстраниться от возможных действий некомпетентных органов, которым дали полномочия. Вряд ли метеоданные будут когда-либо попадать под какие-либо законы... хотя...

Comment: @Konstantin а вы не забывайте про резервирование

Answer (score 0):

У нас была подобная задача, специфика немного другая, но тоже одноплатники. Был один сервер, куда они все стучались, чтобы слить данные и получить обновления. Иногда сервер был загружен, иногда недоступен, в итоге печаль.

Решили через заведение нескольких мелких промежуточных серверов у разных местечковых провайдеров по стране. Например 4. Просто 4 домена или поддомена, на который поочереди (или по длине пинга) заходит каждый одноплатник и спрашивает, куда ему лить данные. Ему отвечают (сейчас всегда один сервер, но можно и балансировать на несколько, если вам нужно), и пошла работа.

Вероятность отказа сразу всех 4 хостингов в разных регионах страны ниже, чем одного сервера в МСК, нас пока такой вариант устроил. VPN не использовали, все дела происходят внутри страны. Пока вроде работает. Если вам не нравится число 4, берите любое, за домены надо платить и за хостинг тоже. Немного, но надо.

В будущем думаем подключить репликацию БД, чтобы собирать данные сразу на всех точках и смешивать, а не на одном сервере.

Я понимаю, что это немного велосипед конечно и на полноценный ответ не тянет. Но этот велосипед решает нашу проблему, поэтому делюсь.

Comment: Да. Рассматривал такую схему со своими узлами, выбор одного из которых берут на себя устройства. VPN рассматриваю только для возможности оперативного управления и получения он-лайн данных без бесконечных циклов. И кстати, одним из клиентов всех VPN может быть машина с БД, в которую будут складываться данные. Осталось придумать защитное размножение узлов на всякий случай.

Comment: Ну вы можете использовать домены 3 уровня вроде node1.domain.zone / node2.domain.zone ... node33.domain.zone, а для каждого домена прописывать в DNS собственный IP адрес хостинга. На одноплатнике просто опрашивать/пинговать первые N штук поддоменов, например первые 128 штук. В этом случае управление будет идти через DNS + IP-адреса ваших машин, и можно будет их менять с оперативностью до 4 часов примерно